# Using Capybara determine whether a form field exists or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, capybara, integration-testing

I want to determine that an `input` field with `id="foo"` exists:

```
<input id="foo" ... />
```

And I also want to ensure that under certain conditions another `input` field with `id="bar"` does **not** exist.

Answer (score 2):

Exists:

```
expect(page).to have_css('#bar')
```

Doesn't exist:

```
expect(page).to have_no_css('#bar')
```

Note: Don't use `expect(page).to_not have_css`, as that will wait for your element to appear.

An explanation of `expect` and negative forms like `has_no_selector?` and `not has_selector?` can be found in [Capybara's Asynchronous JavaScript documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends).

Answer (score 0):

To determine that a particular `input` field exists, use:

```
assert has_xpath?("//input[@id='foo']")
```

To determine that a particular `input` field does **not** exist, use one of:

```
assert has_no_xpath?("//input[@id='bar']")
refute has_xpath?("//input[@id='bar']")
```

[Search for `has_xpath` in these Capybara *node matcher* docs.](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers)